# Position absolute in a position absolute

Tags: css

I got a website to update from a previous design and I noticed something that I'm not happy with.

Normally I'm positioning absolute positioned elements in a relatively positioned parent. But in this site, it has a absolute positioned element inside a absolute positioned parent. Placements are working fine. But I want to make sure whether this is 100% OK or not.

Comment: can you post any code?

Comment: I think you don't need a code for this. But thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any problem.

`position: relative` means that the element will be positioned *relatively* to its current position.

`position: absolute` means that the element will be positioned relatively to first parent element with *either* `position: relative` **or** `position: absolute`.

So just be careful with the wording of the concept: an element absolutely positioned as a child of another absolutely positioned element, is positioned *relatively* to its parent, not to its *relatively positioned* grandparent.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you understand how positioning works and your element is positioned the way you want it to be:

**Yes, what you're doing is fine.** Browsers should display it uniformly, and the specs imply that it's acceptable [over here in the absolute positioning section.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#absolute-positioning)